# I want to send a url to another php function

Tags: javascript, php, api

```
$bid="http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators?chamber=$chamb&state=$keyword&bioguide_id=$bname&apikey=";
$text=$text."<td id=><a href='#'>Details</a>"."</td>";
```

This is my code, `$bid` is my url, which returns json data.

I want to send this url to another php function, which can parse it and print on browser.

Comment: You need to use AJAX if you want to call a PHP function when the user clicks on something.

Comment: i can not use ajax! has to be done without ajax

Comment: I have done it using hidden variable and javascript function call. thank you for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn").on("click", function() {
           var link = "webservice.php";
           $.get(link, function(data, status){
           alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });   
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents` to get the data returned by the API, and `json_decode()` to convert it to PHP arrays.

The link should point to the script that contains code like this:

```
<?php
$bid="http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators?chamber=$chamb&state=$keyword&bioguide_id=$bname&apikey=";
$json = file_get_contents($bid);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
other_function($data);
```

Everything that `other_function()` prints will be sent to the browser.